# Omitting Event Type in Competing Risk CIF Plot Using ggcompetingrisks

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survival-analysis

I was wondering if there is any way to omit a certain event type from the ggcompetingrisks function. Here is my code below.

```
cifit_apr22 <- cuminc(
                ftime = cif_ds$TTE,
                fstatus = cif_ds$SurvivalStatus,
                cencode = 0
               )

FGest_apr22 <- ggcompetingrisks(cifit_apr22,
                                gnames = NULL,
                                multiple_panels = FALSE,
                                conf.int = TRUE,
                                risk.table = TRUE,
                                palette = c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"),
                                xlab = "Time from discharge of first hospital admission (months)",
                                ylab = "Cumulative Incidence",
                                xlim = c(0, 140),
                                ylim = c(0, 0.6),
                                ggtheme = theme_classic2()
                                )
```